# Resque.enqueue failing on second run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I am trying to port an app from Rails 3.0.3 to Rails 3.1rc... I don't think I've missed out anything, in terms of configuration. The process works perfectly in Rails 3.0.X and not in 3.1rc.

In console, I do:

```
Resque.enqueue(EncodeSong, Song.find(20).id, Song.find(20).unencoded_url)
```

Everything works so far. Resque-web reports no failed jobs. And, I get the two 'puts' from module EncodeSong.

However, running **Resque.enqueue(EncodeSong, Song.find(20).id, Song.find(20).unencoded_url)** a second time will return the following error in resque-web (below). To make the error go away, I would have to close the process thats running: **QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work** and rerun it in the console window. But the problem comes back after trying to Resque.enqueue() after the first time.

```
Class
    EncodeSong
Arguments

    20
    "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/unencoded/users/1/songs/test.mp3"

Exception
    PGError
Error
    server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:272:in `exec'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:272:in `block in clear_cache!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:271:in `each_value'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:271:in `clear_cache!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:299:in `disconnect!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `block in disconnect!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `each'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `disconnect!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:35:in `block in disconnect_with_synchronization!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:34:in `disconnect_with_synchronization!'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:407:in `remove_connection'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:116:in `remove_connection'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:79:in `establish_connection'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    /Users/Chris/Sites/site_name/lib/tasks/resque.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:355:in `call'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:355:in `run_hook'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:162:in `perform'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:130:in `block in work'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:116:in `loop'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/worker.rb:116:in `work'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/tasks.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Here is the rest of my relevant code:

**/config/initializers/resque.rb**

```
require 'resque'

uri = URI.parse(APP_CONFIG['redis_to_go_url'])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

# Load all jobs at /app/jobs
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

**/app/jobs/encode_song.rb**

```
module EncodeSong
  @queue = :encode_song

  def self.perform(media_id, s3_file_url)
    begin
      media = Song.find(media_id)
      puts 'foo11111'
      puts media.id
    rescue
      puts "Error #{$!}"
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  # ONLY on Heroku, since they are still running PostgreSql 8 on their shared plan.
  # This block of code is not needed on PostgreSql 9, as tested on local environment.
  # Issue: My best guess is that master resque process establishes connection to db,
  # while loading rails app classes, models, etc, and that connection becomes corrupted
  # in fork()ed process (on exit?). Possible fix is to reestablish the connection the AR
  # after a Resque fork.
  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

Not very sure, but it may be somewhat related to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611747/rails-resque-workers-fail-with-pgerror-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedly). My guess is that master resque process establishes connection to db, while loading rails app classes, models, etc, and that connection becomes corrupted in fork()ed process (on exit?).

Any help / direction will be appreciated.

***EDIT:***

If I remove the following block from **lib/tasks/resque.rake**:

```
  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

And in console, run **Resque.enqueue(EncodeSong, Song.find(20).id, Song.find(20).unencoded_url)**

I get a new error (in console where QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work was run):

```
Error PGError: ERROR:  prepared statement "a3" already exists
: SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs"  WHERE "songs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

It seems, this may be a bug with the adapter? Could be wrong here. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This has solved it for me:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end
```

Source: [carhartl comment on Github](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/306#issuecomment-1421034)

Comment: Thanks, I've read about using `before_fork` somewhere as well. Don't know what implications there are compared to `after_fork`

Comment: Can you add the filename for your code, so we know where to put it? Thanks!

Comment: I put this in `lib/tasks/resque.rake`.

Comment: It would be better to use the `after_fork` hook, in order to establish a new connection on the child process instead of on the parent process. (PS: I'm the maintainer of resque)