# Resque/Rails/Heroku: PG::Error: result has been cleared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, backgroundworker, resque

I'm trying to make resque work with heroku. It works with my other application but I don't understand this error in the worker logs:

```
PG::Error: result has been cleared: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

So whenever I add a job to the queue, a worker takes the job and throws the error above.

Here is the worker class:

```
class Companies
  @queue = :companies

  def self.perform(current_user_id, model)
    @current_user = User.find(current_user_id)

    ... do things with @current_user and model...
  end
end
```

And I call the perform action using: `Resque.enqueue(Companies, current_user.id, 'quotes')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message indicates an internal error in the PG gem that is being used to interface with the Postgres database.  It indicates a Garbage Collection/memory allocation error where the result of the executed postgres query has been cleared from memory on access.

Someone as heroku will have to debug this, it appears to be a platform level issue.

Comment: While I agree with your diagnosis, your conclusion that this is a Heroku platform level issue seems off. Heroku does not control the version of pg you use, nor the web server you choose (Puma, Unicorn, Thin, et. al), which all have implications there. As @wuputah mentioned, this can usually be addressed in the app by handling connections in forked/threaded environments better.

Answer (score 4):

This is most frequently related to multiple processes/threads sharing the same connection. Are you using something a callback (either `after_fork` or `before_hook`) to reconnect to the database for each job?

For more on this, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519372/66752