# "pg" Ruby gem is throwing a "prepared statement already exists" error from Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, resque, pg

Apparently the `pg` gem uses `prepared statements` for Postgres. I have seen fixes for Unicorn to ensure that each process uses it's own db connection like so:

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

But I have no idea how to make this work with Resque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Please look at `Christian Fazzini`'s answer here:

[Rails Resque workers fail with PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611747/rails-resque-workers-fail-with-pgerror-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedl/5519372#5519372)

The error is different, but Christian's solution is the same, and it works.